# How to Verify Email Without Asking the User to Login to Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-controller

I am developing a Laravel application. My application is using Laravel built-in auth feature. In the Laravel auth when a user registers, a verification email is sent. When a user verifies the email click on the link inside the email, the user has to login again to confirm the email if the user is not already logged in.

**VerificationController**

```php
class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails, RedirectsUsersBasedOnRoles;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    public function redirectPath()
    {
        return $this->getRedirectTo(Auth::guard()->user());
    }
}
```

I tried commenting on this line.

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

But it's s not working and instead, throwing an error. How can I enable Laravel to be able to verify email even if the user is not logged in?

Comment: Why do you want this? I can just MitM that email and hijack any account now.

Comment: What does `RedirectsUsersBasedOnRoles` do? When you say ‘It is not working.’ what do you mean; you get an error? What kind of error?

Comment: It throws an error because it expects an instance of your user. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f88917adc292e7e2960e9336a0d89206b41155fe/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/VerifiesEmails.php#L35

Comment: Thanks adam. Thanks Loek for pointing out with a reasonable reason. Cheers

Comment: how so @Loek? the url is signed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First, remove the line `$this->middleware('auth');`, like you did.

Next, copy the `verify` method from the `VerifiesEmails` trait to your `VerificationController` and change it up a bit. The method should look like this:

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

    if (!hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified())
        event(new Verified($user));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

This overrides the method in the `VerifiesUsers` trait and removes the authorization check.

**Security (correct me if I'm wrong!)**

It's still secure, as the request is signed and verified. Someone could verify another user's email address if they somehow gain access to the verification email, but in 99% of cases this is hardly a risk at all.

Comment: So can I use this method without worrying about security issues?

Comment: This was edited for laravel 6?  In previous versions, your custom hash comparison is not mandatory, right?

Comment: Call to undefined method App\User::getEmailForVerification()

Comment: @SeadLab make sure you include the MustVerifyEmail trait on the User model. Other than that, I'm not sure if anything changed in Laravel 7.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more future proof solution to the problem:

```php
class VerificationController extends Controller
{

    // …

    use VerifiesEmails {
        verify as originalVerify;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth'); // DON'T REMOVE THIS
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     *
     * @throws AuthorizationException
     */
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        $request->setUserResolver(function () use ($request) {
            return User::findOrFail($request->route('id'));
        });
        return $this->originalVerify($request);
    }
}
```

So when an email confirmation link is clicked by an unauthenticated user the following will happen:

1. User will be redirected to the login view <sup>1</sup>
2. User enters credentials; logs in successfully <sup>2</sup>
3. User will be redirect back to the email confirmation URL
4. Email will be marked as confirmed

---

<sup>1</sup> The email will not be marked as confirmed at this point.

<sup>2</sup> The user may enter bad credentials multiple times. As soon as he enters the correct credentials he will be redirected to the intended email confirmation URL.

Comment: However, the VerifiesEmails trait was removed in the Laravel 7.x

Comment: I get "You must verify your email first" with this.

Answer (score 4):

Solution to allow email verification for users who are not logged in (i.e. without auth):

Changes to: app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php:

1. `$this->middleware('auth');` to `$this->middleware('auth')->except('verify');`
2. Copy `verify()` method from the `VerifiesEmails` trait.
3. Edit verify method to work without expected `$request->user()` data.

My `verify()` method in the `VerificationController` looks like this:

```
public function verify(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

    if ($request->route('id') != $user->getKey()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified())
        event(new Verified($user));

    return redirect()->route('login')->with('verified', true);
}
```

**Signed middleware**

Laravel uses a middleware named `signed` to check the integrity of URLs that were generated by the application. Signed checks whether the URL has been changed since it was created. Try changing the id, expiry time or the signature in the url and it will lead to an error - very effective and useful middleware to protect the verify() method

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls

(Optional)

I redirected my users to the login route, rather than the intended route for two reasons. 1) After login, it would try to redirect the user to the email verification link, leading to an error; 2) I wanted to use the verified true flash data that was attached to the redirect, to show an alert on the login page, if the user had successfully verified their email address.

Example of my login page alert:

```
@if(session()->has('verified'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">Your email address has been successfully verified.</div>
@endif
```

**Suggestions**

If you have any suggestions on how I could improve this code, please let me know. I'd be happy to edit this answer.

Comment: Really well structured, useful answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// For Laravel 6 and Above 
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\User;

// comment auth middleware
//$this->middleware('auth');

public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->route('id'));

    if (!hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified())
        event(new Verified($user));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

Comment: Not useful: exactly the same code as in the accepted answer, and added after the last edit on it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not remove `$this->middleware('auth')` altogether as that will effect the redirects. If you remove it, the unauthenticated users will be redirected to "/email/verify" instead of "/login"

so `$this->middleware('auth');` will be changed to `$this->middleware('auth')->except('verify');` in "VerificationController"

Also copy the "verify" function from "VerifiesEmails" into "VerificationController"

add these two lines of code at the top of the function

```
$user = User::find($request->route('id'));

auth()->login($user);
```

so you are logging in the user programmatically and then performing further actions

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the situation. Verification requires user to login before it can complete the verification, so we can override the verify function and login user using ID we received in the link. It is safe cause verify function is not called if Laravel can't verify the signature from URL so even if someone temper the URL they won't be able to bypass it.

Go to your VerificationController and add the following function at the end of the file.

```php
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if (!auth()->check()) {
        auth()->loginUsingId($request->route('id'));
    }

    if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

**Note**

Make sure you have same_site value in 'config/session.php' set to 'lax'. If it is set to 'strict' then it won't persist session if you were redirected from another site. For example, if you click a verification link from Gmail then your session cookie won't persist, so it won't redirect you to dashboard, but it sets 'email_verified_at' field in the database marking the verification successful. The user won't get any idea what was happened because it will redirect the user to the login page. When you have set it to 'strict', it will work if you copy the verification link directly in the browser address bar but not if the user clicks the link from the Gmail web client because it uses redirect to track the link.

Comment: nice try. working as expected for me. thanks

Comment: I had to remove `$this->middleware('auth')` to make it work

Answer (score 1):

if you want to active user account without login you can do that in 2 steps

1- Remove or comment Auth middleware in VerificationController

Example below:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
```

2- since verify route passing the {id} you can just edit verify function to find the user by the route id request like code below :

file path : *:\yourproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails.php

```
$user = User::findOrfail($request->route('id'));
```

Complete example

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrfail($request->route('id'));

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $user->getKey())) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('registered', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Surf. Please consider adding a description to your code example.

Answer (score 1):

To use inner laravel logic (without overriding the logic), we simply create $request->user() and call trait's verify method. And manually sign in the user when the verification is successful.

```
use VerifiesEmails {
    verify as parentVerify;
}

public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->route('id'));
    if (!$user) return abort(404);

    $request->setUserResolver(function () use($user) {
        return $user;
    });

    return $this->parentVerify($request);
}


public function verified(Request $request)
{
    Auth::login($request->user());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change EmailVerificationRequest but i now this is wrong, any way it's work.
**Warning**
This change on the vendor

```
protected $user;
public function authorize()
{
    $this->user = \App\Models\User::find($this->route('id'));
    if ($this->user != null){
        if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('id'),
            (string) $this->user->getKey())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('hash'),
            sha1($this->user->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```